# Update script tag attributes in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

in the following block of code, i try to update dynamically the data-url attribute when the page loads:

```
<div id="linkedIn">
        <script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">
          lang: en_US
        </script>
        <script type="IN/Share" data-url=""></script>
</div>
```

My JS:

```
var url = window.location.href; 
$('script[type="IN/Share"]').attr("data-url",url);
```

I already tried to use data instead of attr after some searches, the problem is still not solved. it keeps returning "undefined".
Thanks for your help

Comment: You code works http://jsfiddle.net/Lsba29gj/

Comment: check you include jquery .. sometimes simple things make more problems :)

Comment: What keeps returning undefined? There are no getters or returns shown in your code and you can't write code inside a scipt tag that has an `src`. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're facing is that the included script changes the type attribute that you use for selecting an element. It changes it to `type="IN/Share+init"` so either add an id to a script element and select based on it, recommended, or use the changed value to set the `data-url` attribute, a working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/yscz77g3/2/

```
var url = window.location.href;
var $el =  $("#test"); // recommended
   // $('script[type="IN/Share+init"]'); // or uncomment and target the changed type

$el.attr("data-url",url);
alert($el.attr("data-url"));
```

html

```
<div id="linkedIn">

        <script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">
          lang: en_US
        </script>

        <script id="test" type="IN/Share" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
        </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware of the fact that:

1. the source code of the rendered page is not affected by your javascript
2. but the DOM-state is (when you inspect your element you'll see the changes).
3. and you usually want to perform these actions (or at least the logical following actions) when you're sure your document has fully loaded. Wrap them in something like $(document).ready(function(){});